# How do I scale a joystick axis to be less sensitive?

Tags: input-devices, gamepad, joystick

I have found testing and configuration options for my gamepad

[image]

The problem I am having is that the input reaches its extreme values (+/- 32767) when the joystick is only physically about halfway across. In other words, it is too sensitive. When I calibrate, these values are saturated too soon.

Intuitively, I feel like the range values should be roughly doubled in order to correct this (so that when the device reports ~30000 when the joystick is halfway over, this is about half of the full range) but the configuration panel does not allow min/max values of such size to be entered.

If I reduce RangeMin/RangeMax, the joystick becomes more sensitive, so I think my intuition is correct.

How can I scale the joystick axes to make them *less* sensitive?

Comment: Did you fully move the sticks around (after turning the gamepad on) prior to using the calibration software? Some gamepads are self-calibrating, they track and update the max and min values per axis during usage. This is true for my gamepads from Thrustmaster. Immediately after powering on, they are very sensitive. I then just roll each stick around by 360° and the issue is gone.

Comment: Yes I have used full range of motion before, during, and after calibration.